# How to display a donut chart Inside a donut?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, morris.js, donut-chart

I am trying some visualisation where I need a donut inside a donut, something like this:

Outer donut is divided into 3 parts, for e.g.:

1. A (45)
2. B (30)
3. C (25)
   Total = 100

Inner donut will provide information about each part in the outer donut. For e.g.:

1. A (45) -> a1 (10) ,a2 (20), a3 (15)
2. B (30) -> b1 (10), b2 (15), b3(5)
3. C (25) -> c1 (5), c2 (10), c3(10)

I want to do it using Morris.js donut visualisation, is it possible?

Comment: Highcharts, a Javascript-based chart library with which I'm familiar, can do this. Here is a working example from their website: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut. I don't know morris.js, so I can't provide you with any advice for that library.

Comment: What is A, B and C? And subsequently the minor ones a1, a2, ... , c3?